# User-understandable JsonMappingException

Tags: java, json, error-handling, jackson

I am using Jackson to read a user-provided JSON file, mapping it on an object. In case of error in the JSON structure, I get a `JsonMappingException` that is not readable by the user. For example:

```
my.package.shadow.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Class java.util.ArrayList not subtype of [map type; class java.util.Map, [simple type, class java.lang.String] -> [collection type; class java.util.List, contains [simple type, class java.lang.String]]] (through reference chain: my.package.configuration.Configuration["conf"]->java.util.HashMap["foo"])
    at my.package.shadow.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.wrapWithPath(JsonMappingException.java:391)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class java.util.ArrayList not subtype of [map type; class java.util.Map, [simple type, class java.lang.String] -> [collection type; class java.util.List, contains [simple type, class java.lang.String]]]
    at my.package.shadow.jackson.databind.type.TypeFactory.constructSpecializedType(TypeFactory.java:357)
    ...
```

Is there a way to get a more readable error message, or the line and column in the JSON source that corresponds to the exception?

---

To clarify, the user writes this

```
{
    "conf": {
        "foo": ["bar"]
    }
}
```

but I expect

```
{
    "conf": {
        "foo": {
            "bar" : ["a", "b", "c"]
        }
    }
}
```

---

A snippet of the code:

```
public class ReadConfiguration {
    public static Configuration readConfiguration(File file) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new JsonFactory());
        Configuration conf = mapper.readValue(file, Configuration.class);
        return conf
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the JSON you have?

Comment: @Sidhu I wrote an example, it should correspond to the exception